# FBProphet model giving random result on live streaming data

Tags: facebook-prophet

I have trained FBprophet model on crypto data, on backtesting it gives me more than 85% results, but when I try to connect it with live Binance API then it gives random results (50-50%), the model is trained on hourly time frame, so during live the code waits for 1 hours to complete then it does the prediction. I have tried many things even NEWTON, but it didn't work. Following is the code snippet.

```
********************Training CODE*******
                    recent_result["ds"] = recent_result["open_time"]
                    recent_result["y"] = recent_result["open"]

                    logging.info(f"Model Retrained Begin")

                    model_60_mins = Prophet(
                        daily_seasonality=True
                        
                    )

                    model_60_mins.add_regressor("high")
                    model_60_mins.add_regressor("low")
                    model_60_mins.add_regressor("close")
                    model_60_mins.add_regressor("volume")
                    model_60_mins.add_regressor("Returns")
                    model_60_mins.add_regressor("Log Returns")
                    model_60_mins.add_regressor("BBANDS")
                    model_60_mins.add_regressor("RSI")
                    model_60_mins.add_regressor("MACD")
                    model_60_mins.add_regressor("SMA")
                    model_60_mins.add_regressor("EMA")

                    random.seed(1234)
                    model_60_mins.fit(recent_result)

************
******************Live code ****
        recent_result = get_last_hour_tiker(spot_client) ### get last hour ticker value

        # getting predicted value
        predicted_time = recent_result.iloc[-1]["open_time"] + timedelta(minutes=60)

        future = pd.DataFrame()
        future["ds"] = [predicted_time]
        future["y"] = [recent_result.iloc[-1]["open"]]

        future["high"] = [recent_result.iloc[-1]["high"]]
        future["low"] = [recent_result.iloc[-1]["low"]]
        future["close"] = [recent_result.iloc[-1]["close"]]
        future["volume"] = [recent_result.iloc[-1]["volume"]]
        future["Returns"] = [recent_result.iloc[-1]["Returns"]]
        future["Log Returns"] = [recent_result.iloc[-1]["Log Returns"]]
        future["BBANDS"] = [recent_result.iloc[-1]["BBANDS"]]
        future["RSI"] = [recent_result.iloc[-1]["RSI"]]
        future["MACD"] = [recent_result.iloc[-1]["MACD"]]
        future["SMA"] = [recent_result.iloc[-1]["SMA"]]
        future["EMA"] = [recent_result.iloc[-1]["EMA"]]

        # forecasting the predicted value
        random.seed(1234)
        forecast = model_60_mins.predict(future)
```

I tried seed value, even newton but none worked. No matter what I do backtesting results are good but when live are about 50-50.
Can someone help me out on what exactly is happening here or what I am doing wrong?

I have tried newton algo, random seed

Comment: I resolved the issue, the problem was with our logic in terms of using Binance API. It was very silly mistable, we were assuming the binance would return last consolidate row when we hit KLINE API, but it was not the case.